# Degree of $x^{4}-4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I need to find the degree of the splitting field of $x^{4}-4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}$.

I know that the roots are $\pm\sqrt{2}, \pm \sqrt{2}i$, so the splitting field is $F(\sqrt{2},i)\cong \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$. Since $i \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ then  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})] = 2$, because $x^{2}+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ then by multiplication of degrees  $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$, is that correct?

In the other case we have that $x^{4}-4 = (x^{2}-2)(x^{2}+2) = (x^{2}-2)(x^{2}-3)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}$, then the roots are $\pm\sqrt{2}, \pm\sqrt{3}$, and the slitting field would be $\mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ which is of degree 4.

I do not know if what I did is right?

Thanks

Comment: How is $\mathbb{Q}$ a $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$-vector space?

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the polynomial reduces over $\mathbb Q$ and, in fact, $\mathbb Z$

Comment: The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}$ is not $1$. The polynomial $x-i$ does not have coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: Can you fix the question first? As asked, it's difficult to tell where you have problems and where you are simply sloppy. Concrete points: (1) in the first part, all $F$ should be ${\mathbb Q}$; (2) $2 \cdot 2 = 4$; (3) in the second part, ${\mathbb Q}$ is not a ${\mathbb Z}/5$ vector space - what is it that you want to say there?

Comment: Just one more nitpick: using $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ to denote elements of (field extensions of) finite fields is rather uncustomary.

Comment: Is the polynomial $x^4+4$ or $x^4-4$? You have two different versions in the title and the body.

Comment: you are right, the correct question is $x^{4} -4$. I just corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct for the case over ${\mathbb Q}$.

The case over ${\mathbb F}_5$ is wrong. If you'd follow the same argument as the one over ${\mathbb Q}$, you'd see that once you adjoin an element $\alpha$ with $\alpha^2 = 2$ to ${\mathbb F}_5$, you automatically get an element $\beta$ with $\beta^2 = 3$ (namely $\beta = 2\alpha$).

(Note: since there is upto isomorphism only one field of $25$ elements, every polynomial of degree 2 over ${\mathbb F}_5$ necessarily splits over ${\mathbb F}_{25}$. This is why you can immediately see that ${\mathbb F}_5[\alpha]$ must contain a $\beta$ with $\beta^2 = 3$ without further computation.),

Comment: (Alternately, for the relatively simple case here one can simply note that if $\alpha^2=2$ then $(2\alpha)^2 = -\alpha^2=3$.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Agreed; I've added it to the answer.